# "FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context" error showing while registering FCM service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm writing a simple script for a friend that will receive notifications from a python backend using Firebase Cloud Messaging. First, I made the client side in Angular and it worked just fine. However, I was asked to redo the client side in vanilla js. I followed the steps mentioned in the firebase documentation (I linked the necessary scripts in index html, got the client token, etc). No matter what i tried however, i always got the same error:

> [Mentioned SW error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSgZk.png)

When I send a notification using my python backend firebase registers it, but nothing is received on the client side:

> [FCM reporting dashboard] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqwuT.png)

I cannot tell what I am doing wrong :/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script>

    //Config
    const firebasedConfig = {
        (...)
    }
    

    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebasedConfig)
    const messaging = firebase.messaging(app)
    const db = firebase.database(app)
    const vapidKey = "my public vapid key"

    //Token
    const FCMToken = "";
    window.addEventListener('click', () => {
        messaging.getToken({vapidKey: vapidKey}).then( (token) => {
        if(token){
            console.log("Token - ", token)
        } else{
            console.log("Token isn't available")
        }
        }).catch((err) =>{
            console.log('Error occurred while retrieving token - ', err)
        })
    })

    //Messaging
    messaging.onMessage((payload)=>{
        console.log("onMessage event fired", payload)
    })

    //SW
    async function registerWorker(){
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {scope: "/"})
        console.log("Service worker registered")
        const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: vapidKey
        })
        console.log(subscription)
    }

    if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        console.log("Registering service worker...")
        registerWorker().catch(error => console.log(error))
    } else{
        console.log("Service worker not available")
    }

    </script>
    
    <script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>


    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Click</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js:**

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) =>{
  console.log('Background message received: ', payload)
  const notificationTitle = "Title"
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload
  }
  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
})
```

**python class:**

```
from firebase_admin import messaging, credentials
import firebase_admin
class Pusher:
    def __init__(self):
        #credentials.json is where I store app config
        cred = credentials.Certificate('credentials.json')
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    def subscribe(self, tokens, topic):
        response = messaging.subscribe_to_topic(tokens, topic)

    def unsubscribe(self, tokens, topic):
        response = messaging.unsubscribe_from_topic(tokens, topic)

    def push_notification_by_topic(self, title, body, topic):
        message = messaging.Message(
            notification=messaging.Notification(title=title, body=body),
            topic=topic
        )
        response = messaging.send(message)

    def push_notification_by_one_token(self, title, body, token):
        message = messaging.Message(
            notification=messaging.Notification(title=title, body=body),
            token=token
        )
        response = messaging.send(message)

    def push_notification_by_tokens(self, title, body, tokens):
        message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
            notification=messaging.Notification(title=title, body=body),
            tokens=tokens
        )
        response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
```

**main.py:**

```
from pusher import Pusher

def main():
    app = Pusher()
    token = "token i copied from the client"
    app.push_notification_by_tokens(title="Title", body="Body", tokens=[token])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Like mentioned earlier, message sent is registered by firebase, so I don't think it's backend's fault.

I tried to find an answer in the documentation, but even following the instructions to the word not solve the problem. After digging thru the internet and some youtube tutorials I still couldn't make it work.

> Docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive